# Can I say if $A$ is a projection then $\ker A= (\text{Im } A)^{\perp}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $A\in M_{n \times n}$ and $A^2=A$. Prove that $\ker A= (\text{Im } A)^{\perp}$.

I want to show this statement is true or not. I know that $A$ is a orthogonal projection $\iff$ $A=A^2=A^*$.

Comment: The red flag that should pop out into your head is that the definition of a projection doesn't involve any inner products, whereas the definition of an orthogonal complement does, so the answer is very likely no. This sort of thing is more obvious if you don't think about real-valued columns and matrices and instead think of abstract linear spaces and transformations.

Comment: I disagree slightly with Dan -- I think that familiarity with all concepts *in terms of* real-valued columns can be a great tool for constructing counterexamples. In fact, I'd say that 90% of my counterexamples are 1x1 or 2x2. The key thing in THIS problem is to notice that you're given $A = A^2$, but that orthogonal  projection means $A = A*$. So to find a counterexample, you need to find a matrix $A$ with $A = A^2$, but $A \ne A*$.

Comment: I agree with your advice @JohnHughes as I have provided a zero matrix and the identity matrix as counter-examples to questions here. Sometimes simple solutions are overlooked because we get caught up in abstraction.

Comment: I want to also say that I really *agree* with Dan as well --- there's a value to asking early on "could this *possibly* be true???", and in particular, doing it in the way that he describes. But that's usually step 2 for me. Step 1 is "lemme see if there's a stupid example which will bring enlightenment." In the case of this problem, projection along the direction (1, -1) into the $x$-axis seems like a good tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider
$$
\pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0}.
$$